# Create service installer for existing C# console application in Visual Studio 2015 Community

Tags: c#, windows-7, windows-services, visual-studio-2015

I have an app (C# Console application).
 I know that in Visual Studio 2008 was the template for creating "Setup project".
In Visual Studio 2015 Community this template is not available.
What tools inside VS 2015 could help me to pack my app as a Windows service (within Windows 7) and create installer for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check out this extension for vs2k15:
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f1cc3f3e-c300-40a7-8797-c509fb8933b9

Also the learning curve is a bit steep but WiX is widely accepted as a very good solution for creating installers for windows apps.  Read more about it here:

http://wixtoolset.org/

Comment: Thanks, very helpful!