# How do I create an installer with only exe and no dependencies in Winforms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have seen applications that once installed only have a `.exe` file in the folder and no dependencies that is (no `dll`, no `xml`, no `ico`) nothing. I have seen one in a **Point of Sale** application.

How do I do this using `Visual Studio`, `Winforms` and `C#`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189549/embedding-dlls-in-a-compiled-executable

Comment: https://helpdeskgeek.com/free-tools-review/4-tools-to-create-windows-installer-packages/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create service installer for existing C# console application in Visual Studio 2015 Community](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39778460/create-service-installer-for-existing-c-sharp-console-application-in-visual-stud)

Answer (score 0):

To merge dependencies (DLLs and assemblies) you can use Microsoft [ILMerge](https://github.com/dotnet/ILMerge). ILMerge is a utility that merges multiple .NET assemblies into a single assembly.

> ILMerge takes a set of input assemblies and merges them into one
>   target assembly. The first assembly in the list of input assemblies is
>   the primary assembly. When the primary assembly is an executable, then
>   the target assembly is created as an executable with the same entry
>   point as the primary assembly. Also, if the primary assembly has a
>   strong name, and a .snk file is provided, then the target assembly is
>   re-signed with the specified key so that it also has a strong name.

Example:

```
    @echo off

:: this script needs https://www.nuget.org/packages/ilmerge

:: set your target executable name (typically [projectname].exe)
SET APP_NAME=myapp.exe

:: Set build, used for directory. Typically Release or Debug
SET ILMERGE_BUILD=Debug

:: Set platform, typically x64
SET ILMERGE_PLATFORM=x64

:: set your NuGet ILMerge Version, this is the number from the package manager install, for example:
:: PM> Install-Package ilmerge -Version 3.0.21
:: to confirm it is installed for a given project, see the packages.config file
SET ILMERGE_VERSION=3.0.21

:: the full ILMerge should be found here:
SET ILMERGE_PATH=%USERPROFILE%\.nuget\packages\ilmerge\%ILMERGE_VERSION%\tools\net452
:: dir "%ILMERGE_PATH%"\ILMerge.exe

echo Merging %APP_NAME% ...

:: add project DLL's starting with replacing the FirstLib with this project's DLL
"%ILMERGE_PATH%"\ILMerge.exe Bin\x64\Release\%APP_NAME%  ^
  /lib:Bin\%ILMERGE_PLATFORM%\%ILMERGE_BUILD%\ ^
  /out:%APP_NAME% ^
  FirstLib.dll ^
  mylib1.dll ^
  Microsoft.lib2.dll ^
  SomeOtherLib.dll ^
  \otherlibdir\otherlib.dll 


:Done
dir %APP_NAME%
```

If it's hard for you to use ILMerge in command-line or in your build process I suggest [ILMerge-Gui tool](https://bitbucket.org/wvd-vegt/ilmergegui). It gives you short and simple UI to merge your dependencies as a single exe file.

[image: IL Merge]

Please don't forget to read the ILMerge website.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Fody-Costura](https://github.com/Fody/Costura/). It comes as a NuGet package and merges dependecies so that you have one .exe at the end. Worked perfectly for me.